Run ASP.NET Core Backend in Azure DevOps CI Environment with Docker
I'm working on a project in Azure DevOps and my basic goal is to run End2End Tests in the CI Pipeline. For that, I try to serve the Backend with docker-compose and also let the backend Deliver the Frontend by serving it from wwwroot as static files.
Here is my docker-compose:
version: "3.8"

volumes:
  mongo-data:

services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: ticket-machine-mongodb
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    volumes:
      - mongo-data:/data/db
    healthcheck:
      test: echo 'db.runCommand("ping").ok' | mongosh localhost:27017/test --quiet
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 1s
      retries: 10
  
  backend:
    container_name: ticket-machine-backend
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Test
      - CI=true
    depends_on:
      mongodb:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - "5173:5000"
      - "5000:5000"

The Dockerfile looks like this:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000

COPY ./app/ .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "VHS.TicketMachine.Web.dll"]

Most of this I got from a different project within my company and tried to modify it to work for me as well. When I run my things locally like
dotnet publish --nologo --no-restore --configuration Release --output image/app
Copy-Item -Path "C:\Users\lejm\RiderProjects\VHS-TicketMachine\VHS.TicketMachine.Frontend\dist" -Destination "image\app\wwwroot" -Recurse -Force
docker-compose -f .\image\docker-compose.vhs.yml up -d

It works just fine. It runs on port 5000 and 5173, I can access my frontend content and requests are made to the backend successfully. My End 2 End tests also run when It's running in the container.
Now here's the CI-Pipeline (part of it):
# ... Install Node, npm i, npm run build
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: Publish Backend
    inputs:
      zipAfterPublish: false
      modifyOutputPath: false
      command: publish
      arguments: >-
        --nologo
        --no-restore
        --configuration Release
        --output image/app
  - task: CopyFiles@2
    displayName: Publish Frontend
    inputs:
      sourceFolder: $(frontendDir)/dist
      targetFolder: image/app/wwwroot
  
  - script: |
      docker-compose -f ./image/docker-compose.vhs.yml up -d
    displayName: "Run Docker image"

  - script: |
      export VITE_FRONTEND_URL=http://localhost:5173/
      npx playwright install --with-deps chromium
      npx playwright test
    displayName: Run End 2 End Tests
    workingDirectory: $(frontendDir)

The End 2 End Tests respond with this:
Error: page.goto: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED at http://localhost:5173/question Call log: - navigating to "http://localhost:5173/question", waiting until "load"
And it also failed my curl health checks. I tried with network_mode: "host", but it didn't do anything, apparently it doesn't work in windows pipelines, although I thought I'm on ubuntu anyways, I'm not sure though. Also used a custom bridge network, which gave the same result. (All of these things worked locally btw.) I also tried running on docker.host.internal instead of localhost, but that doesn't work as well. I don't really know what to try anymore and I don't understand what exactly doesn't work here. (I'm not very experienced with docker). I would really appreciate if someone could help me out here, thank you!

In a Dockerized setup, localhost does not refer to the host machine or other containers but to the container itself.
When using Docker Compose, services communicate with each other via their service names defined in the docker-compose.yml file. So, instead of:
mongodb://admin:password@localhost:27017

You should use:
mongodb://admin:password@mongodb:27017

Here, mongodb is the service name for your MongoDB container as defined in your docker-compose.yml. Docker's internal networking will resolve this name to the appropriate container.
To ensure this configuration only applies in your CI environment, you can set it conditionally through environment variables or CI-specific configuration files. For example, in your .env file for CI:
MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING=mongodb://admin:password@mongodb:27017

Then make sure your application reads this value dynamically.

Thank you so much man, I've been struggling for so long. Can't believe that the mistake was literally just one word . I will forever be in your debt, thanks!
